# No instance error when calling CanvasWatchFaceService

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

When i am calling "private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine", i'm getting the error of 'No enclosing instance of type 'android.support.wearable.watchface.CanvasWatchFaceService' is in scope'

I have called imported the class import android.support.wearable.watchface.CanvasWatchFaceService; but it says it's a unused import statement

UPDATED: This is the whole of my MyWatchFace.java

```
package com.projects.kainowitzke.googlewatchface;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.CanvasWatchFaceService;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.WatchFaceService;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.CanvasWatchFaceService;

public class MyWatchface {
}

public class AnalogWatchFaceService extends MyWatchface {

@Override
public WatchFaceService.Engine onCreateEngine() {
    /* provide your watch face implementation */
    return new CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine();
}

/* implement service callback methods */
    private class MyWatchfac extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onCreate(holder);
        /* initialize your watch face */
    }

    @Override
    public void onPropertiesChanged(Bundle properties) {
        super.onPropertiesChanged(properties);
        /* get device features (burn-in, low-bit ambient) */
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeTick() {
        super.onTimeTick();
        /* the time changed */
    }

    @Override
    public void onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAmbientMode) {
        super.onAmbientModeChanged(inAmbientMode);
        /* the wearable switched between modes */
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
        /* draw your watch face */
    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
        /* the watch face became visible or invisible */
    }
}
```

}

Comment: post your stacktrace...

Comment: You say `AnalogWatchFaceService extends MyWatchface` but what is `MyWatchface`?

Answer (score 0):

`MyWatchface` must extend `CanvasWatchFaceService`.